# webdriver python how to "click" required button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

What I want is to use find element to click on the line "linked formlink" that has "Assigned" type.

But whatever I use the xpath, it return me " unable to locate the element".

Does any better way to sort out the required element and proceed click operation by using webdriver python?

```
element2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='linked formlink'][]").click
```

[the html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7szFR.png)

```
    <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="" tabindex="0"><a class="linked formlink" href="incident.do?sys_id=ca4b12e4db478b8c2a55f4641f9619c3&amp;sysparm_record_target=incident&amp;sysparm_record_row=1&amp;sysparm_record_rows=20&amp;sysparm_record_list=active%3Dtrue%5Eassigned_toDYNAMICjavascript%3Anew+approvalFilters%28%29.getMyAssignments%28%29%5EstateNOT+IN6%2C77%2C99%2C9%5EORDERBYDESCopened_at">INC1471130</a></td>
    <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">Assigned</td>
```

Comment: Please edit the question and include the HTML code as a string, not as an image.

Comment: if element is invisible then Selenium may have to scroll page to see it. There are solutions with javascript.

Comment: Hum... I think it's visible, I can click it on web page

Comment: Do you see it when you open browser or you have to scroll it ? If you have to scroll to see it then it is not visible for Selenium too - and it has to scroll too.

Comment: better always add url to page so everyone could test it.

Comment: sorry it's an internal web, so you might not be able to visit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `click()` on the button with text as **`Assigned`** you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='linked formlink' and contains(@href,'incident.do?sys_id=')]//following::td[1]").click
```